# How to make permanent system variable using BATCH or VBS?

Tags: windows, windows-7, vbscript, batch-file

I am making an installer which will be 100% depending on system variable such as %TEMP% or %Path%, users first double click `windows.bat` file.

But, How can i setup permanent system variable in Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8 using VBS or BATCH?

I tried with BATCH but in Windows XP, most users do not have `setx` by default, so i want to avoid using that technique. Is there better way to do that?

```
C:\Documents and Settings\sun>REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Ses
sion Manager\Environment" /v MyApplicationWillUsetThis /d "C:\WhatEverPathToIncl
udeHereQuestionMark"

The operation completed successfully

C:\Documents and Settings\sun>REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Ses
sion Manager\Environment" /v MyApplicationWillUsetThis /d "C:\WhatEverPathToIncl
udeHereQuestionMark"
Value MyApplicationWillUsetThis exists, overwrite(Y/N)? Y

The operation completed successfully
```

Comment: Try making your installer only 0% depending on system variables.

Comment: @UweKeim: 0% installer but the application is 100% requires some customized System variables. Specially my third party libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a REG_SZ value under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment in the registry. The name of the value specifies the name of the environment variable, the value specifies the value of the environment variable.

You can also modify existing values.

In order to modify the registry you can use the RegRead and RegWrite method of the WScript.Shell object. For an example have a look at [Manipulating the System Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/swwyb11a).

**Edit:** You could at first delete the existing value and recreate it afterwards.

```
REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v MyApplicationWillUsetThis /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v MyApplicationWillUsetThis /d "C:\WhatEverPathToIncludeHereQuestionMark"
```

Comment: 1) http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html  2) REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v MyApplicationWillUsetThis /d "C:\WhatEverPathToIncludeHereQuestionMark" ?

Comment: Yes, that is another way to do it.

Comment: I did it as above my edit. But it asks Y or N. How to explicitly apply "Yes always" in the command already?

Comment: Windows 7. It says permission denied.

Comment: @Google: Writing to HKLM requires elevated rights since Windows Vista. You could try searching this site for questions about how to check for elevated rights or maybe how to restart the script with elevated rights.

Comment: @Google REG.exe has a `/f` parameter to force overwriting existing keys. This should prevent the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

How to set environment variables from VBScript

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

' set a permanent environment variable %MyVarName% for all users
WshShell.Environment.item("MyVarName") = "MyVarValue"
```

If the above setting isn't permanent, try this one. This will set a permanent environment variable for all users. You can try System, User, Volatile, and Process categories with the Environment collection.

```
With WSHShell.Environment("SYSTEM")
    .item("MyVarName") = "MyVarValue"
End With
```

You can also use ExpandEnvironmentStrings to read environment variables or replace them with their values in long command line type strings.

```
sValue = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%MyVarName%")
```

To work with the registry try

```
sRegKey = "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\MyVarName"

sValue = WshShell.RegRead(sRegKey)

' don't write if no change is required.
If sValue <> sNewValue Then WshShell.RegWrite sRegKey , sNewValue
```